# How can I change the amount of iCloud storage for one family member?

Tags: icloud, storage, family-sharing

I've two kids under 13 set up in my Family Sharing with access to my 2TB iCloud storage.

For some reason, my son has an amount set of 5GB, which is way too low for what he needs on his iPad. His sister has way more (over 200GB) and I don't understand why. I've been looking on forums to see if and how I can change this 5GB limit (as I've plenty of memory available), but I haven't found anything yet.

Can anyone advise me on how I can sort this out?

Answer (score 2):

I know of no way to configure iCloud storage per user in a Family. Most likely your son is limited to 5GB because he is using the 'free' iCloud storage of 5GB. He is either not signed into iCloud or he is signed in under a different account than you have for him in your Family Share. Since your daughter has more than 200GB, she is using the Family Share storage.

Each iCloud account must be added to the Family Share, and each device must be logged into an iCloud account that is in the Family Share.

Answer (score 0):

I would chat with Apple support online before doing anything as drastic as kicking them from the family. A server side look would be the best way to get at the nub of the issue without causing further breakage.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-support/id1130498044

The app on iOS and iPadOS is basically instant and makes it very easy to send a screen shot of details from the device with the issue.